# Transforming WFS Projection

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, wfs, mapserver, coordinate-system

I am trying to overlay features from a WFS using OpenLayers, my geometries in database are in EPSG:27700 and my map's projection is EPSG:3857. My mapfile returns data in EPSG:27700.

Is there any way I can transform points into the map projection?

Here is my code which is not working.

```
var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
            'layername',
            {
                strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    url : 'proxy.php?url=xxx',
                    featureType : 'typename',
                    "geometryName": "msGeometry",
                    "featurePrefix": "ms",
                    "srsName": 'EPSG:3857',
                    "maxFeatures": 1000,
                    "version": "1.0.0"
                })                    
            }
    );
```

Comment: You can create postgis view which uses ST_TRANSFORM(geom,srid) to geom column (or other way around )

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have tried using ST_Transform but unfortunately it creates a shift of 10 meters for each point.

Comment: it seems that your postgig db has "wrong" proj4 definitions for EPSG:27700. Easiest way is create new custom projection and use it or fix existing one in. "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs" is from http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/proj4/ and
"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs" is from my spatial_ref_sys table (postgis 2.0.3 r11132) (same happened 2063 vs 3857 while ago)

Comment: Also there is proj4js for openlayers , but that will create same transformation with same parameters